# Is chili sauce vegan?

Tags: is-it-vegan

I am wondering if [chili sauce](https://english.vov.vn/economy/chinsu-chili-sauce-makes-debut-in-japanese-market-401054.vov) is vegan. Basically this sauce is made from vegetables such as chili or garlic. It is my favourite spice so it's hard to give up.

Comment: Generally yes, chilli sauces are vegan. As for the specific one that you posted, I can only see a link for video of introducing that chilli sauce in Japan so it's hard to say. If you have the bottle at home look at the ingredients list and if you are not sure, feel free to copy it to your answer for people to look at and confirm. I am not sure this is the kind of question this site is for, however, as it seems quite trivial.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is generally vegan. But if you buy the sauce from a store, do check the ingredients since milk (and honey, eggs,...) tends to find its way in many processed foods.

Answer (score 1):

Chili sauce is exactly made from chiles, tomatoes and other ingredients such as garlic. But be careful if you follow vegan diet due to your religion. Those who are Buddhists avoid using garlic because it is root vet which means it gives life. So if you have strict belief, you should choose a product not having garlic as its ingredient.

Answer (score 0):

If your country has the Blue Dragon brand, then I can confirm that is suitable for vegans